# Change the value of passed object in View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I wonder is it possible to change the passed value and update the view's body itself wherein. `ViewModel.value` is updating correctly, but the text is constant forever. I tried with `@State` attribute for value in `ViewModel`, but doesn't work.

```swift
class ViewModel {
    var value: Double = 10

    lazy var view: SomeView = {
        let bind = Binding<Double>(get: {
            self.value
        }, set: {
            self.value = $0
        })
        return SomeView(value: bind)
    }()
}

struct SomeView: View {

    @Binding
    var value: Double

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(value)") // this text is constant
            Slider(value: $value, in: 1...100)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct pattern with pair should be as follows

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: Double = 10
}

struct SomeView: View {

    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(vm.value)") // this text is constant
            Slider(value: $vm.value, in: 1...100)
        }
    }
}
```

Now view model is a source of truth for view and (being dynamic property) updates view whenever published value is changed.

And we create view with view model, but not vice versa.

Comment: I fully agree with your right approach but have a different scenario a bit. I'm making a debug tool and need to generate views directly from models and mutate them afterward. So I consciously sacrifice the architecture. I'd appreciate a lot an explanation of constant text...